# PC not starts if shutdown for more than 8 hours and starts by reconnecting SMPS

Tags: motherboard

My PC is having a weird problem. Sometimes in the morning if doesn't start. CPU fan don't move and no lights turns on.

Then I have to disconnect the connection between Motherboard and SMPS. I keep them disconnect for 2-3 seconds, then connect them back. The PC starts immediately. Now this problem will not repeat unless I keep my PC shutdown for approx 8 hours. I can restart and no problems comes.

My PC is one year old, 4GB RAM, intel i3-3220, Motherboard is intel DH61ZE with Seagate 500 GB harddisk. No graphic/sound or other external card/

Comment: Please describe your pc and power supply a little more.  Also do you live where it's very humid, hot or cold?

Comment: `no lights turns on` means no light on mother board or CPU cabin?

Comment: No lights on CPU power button, but the light do turn on motherboard.

Comment: @ElipticalView   My SMPS is local brand, it is 250 WATT. No I do not live in very humid, hot or cold, though it is litte dusty.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are having a problem with your power supply and/or the switch, wires, etc to it.

If you shutdown.  And then unplug it.  And plug it back in does it start back up, (not the 8 hour test, but just the 10 min. test)?

Then shut it down and start it up 5 more times in a row.  Is it repeatable, i.e. exactly every time the same?

How hard is it to get a new power supply for it?  I suspect there is a bad solder joint or something in the power supply which experiences a little corrosion and after a number of hours makes it cranky.  The easiest thing would be to swap out the power supply with another known good one and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: If you shutdown. And then unplug it. And plug it back in does it start back up, (not the 8 hour test, but just the 10 min. test)? >>>YESSSS. I have tried it repeatly, it always turns back. I don't have another SMPS, and I don't want to buy a new one unless I know that it is faulty SMPS. Can motherboard be faulty?

Comment: I will tell you this.  I have repaired computers for a living and it's far more likely for a power supply to fail than anything else.  A tiny crack in a solder joint can provide an intermittent failure like you describe.  But who knows. The only way you will find your problem is to replace something. It's far easier and cheaper to replace the power supply than anything else.  And because it's very likely the problem I would suggest you replace it. The rule partly is if you have two things that could be causing the problem and one is cheap and the other expensive which one do you replace first?